# Pebble App is not compiling to due image menu icon

Tags: javascript, pebble-sdk, pebble

This is my first pebble app that i am writing using the nextbus api to create a bus time app for pebble. when i hit compile i am hit with an error message of "menuIcon resource 'IMAGE_MENU_ICON' exceeds the maximum allowed dimensions of (25, 25)". I am using CloudPebble and am using Pebble.js.

This is my code.

```
var UI = require('ui');
var Vector2 = require('vector2');
var apiRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

var rutgersBusList = 
"http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?
a=rutgers&command=routeConfig";
var XML_List = apiRequest.open('GET', rutgersBusList, true);

var arr_busList = [];

for(var i = 0; i < XML_List.length; i++) {
  arr_busList.push(XML_List.body[i]);
}

var printBuses = function() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr_busList.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr_busList[i]);
  }
};

var chooseBus = function() {
  var bus = "";
  return bus;
};

var getBusTimes = function(route) {
  var rutgersBusTimes = "http://runextbus.herokuapp.com/route/" + route;
  var JSON_Times = apiRequest.open('GET', rutgersBusTimes, true);
  var arr_busTimes = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < JSON_Times.length; i++) {
    var timesArr = JSON_Times.body[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < timesArr.predictions.length; j++) {
      arr_busTimes.push(timesArr.predictions[i]);
    }
  }

  return arr_busTimes;
 };

apiRequest.onLoad = function() {
  console.log("API Call was successful");
};

for(var i = 0; i < arr_busList.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr_busList[i].title);
}
```

This is my build log.

```
Setting top to                           : /tmp/tmpMgxOI3 
Setting out to                           : /tmp/tmpMgxOI3/build 
Checking for program webpack             : 
/app/node_modules/.bin/webpack 
WARNING: enableMultiJS is not enabled for this project. 
message_keys.json will not be included in your project unless you add it 
to your pebble-js-app.js file. 
Found Pebble SDK for emery in:           : /app/sdk3/pebble/emery 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK for diorite in:         : /app/sdk3/pebble/diorite 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK for chalk in:           : /app/sdk3/pebble/chalk 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK for basalt in:          : /app/sdk3/pebble/basalt 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK for aplite in:          : /app/sdk3/pebble/aplite 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
'configure' finished successfully (0.248s)
Waf: Entering directory `/tmp/tmpMgxOI3/build'
menuIcon resource 'IMAGE_MENU_ICON' exceeds the maximum allowed 
dimensions of (25, 25)
```

Answer (score 0):

In CloudPebble, go to your project settings, locate the entry for the menu icon, make sure the image specified there is an image that is exactly 25x25.